# How to access internal memory of android device with a broken display and without root permission?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, data-recovery

My Samsung Galaxy Grand has a broken display. I need to access my media files( Photos and Videos ) from the internal memory of the device.

**What I have tried -**

1. Tried with Samsung KIES.
2. tried to connect via adb to the device but It's not on USB debugging.
3. Managed to put the device into recovery mode, but on ***adb shell*** mode. I'm not able to see any files under ***sdcard*** and ***sdcard1***. Also my device is **NOT rooted** so I cannot use **su** command

What should I do now to copy the files off the internel memory?

Comment: Better pull the build.prop, Add these lines: 'persist.service.adb.enable=1                                                    
persist.service.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb'

and push it back. Now check if ADB works after rebooting the phone

(Caution: Use Notepad++ for Unix line breaks)

Comment: This may be kind of a crazy idea and is dependent on hardware you may or may not have, but consider using an MHL adapter to connect the device to a TV or monitor and use a Bluetooth mouse to navigate... bypassing your broken screen altogether.

Comment: @GokulNC Tried changing the build.prop, I wasn't able to copy the edited build.prop onto my device because "permission denied"

Comment: @paulmz My device does not support MHL adapter. Thought of that as well earlier :(